# Microsoft Graph API - Get users with specified app roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I have a question about the Graph API. I need to download all users who have been assigned the app role "Role" in "ApplicationA". I need it to download all users with the required app role to send an email. I have tried various ways, through the list of users using the following API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments&$count=true&$filter=appRoleAssignments/any(w:w/appRoleId eq {guid})
```

However this returns the following error, I have of course tried similar options.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Property 'appRoleId' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-02-28T20:49:49",
            "request-id": "bf8991a4-82e9-4136-9664-1cebc1718ae0",
            "client-request-id": "bf8991a4-82e9-4136-9664-1cebc1718ae0"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using servicePrincipals. But this returns all users/applications assigned to the service principal and not just the role I need, and the filtering I tried with OData didn't work. Many items is downloaded:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='{guid}')/appRoleAssignedTo
```

Do you know of a better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: **`appRoleAssignments`** endpoint doesn't support filtering on `appRoleId`. Refer this [**Microsoft  QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/603125/how-to-filter-approleassignments-based-on-approlei) by CarlZhao-MSFT. Hence getting users with specified app roles is not possible.

Assigned users and groups in the Enterprise application:

[image]

As a **workaround** you can list the roles assigned to the users and groups based on the **`resourceID`**.

For ***Users***:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/UserID/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq ServicePrincipalObjID
```

[image]

For ***groups***:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq ServicePrincipalObjID
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that getting users with specified app roles [is not supported yet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/8934#issuecomment-1862856140). And the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) doesn't have a description which support the filter.

[image]

Therefore, we can only do the filter by ourselves. Code snippet below worked in my side.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId ";
var clientId = "clientId ";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret ";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var res = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "appRoleAssignments($select=appRoleId,resourceDisplayName)" };
});
List<User> users = new List<User>();
foreach (var tempUser in res.Value) {
    var roles = tempUser.AppRoleAssignments;
    foreach(var role in roles) {
        if (role.AppRoleId.ToString() == "role_id_here")
        {
            users.Add(tempUser);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```