Microsoft Graph SDK for PowerShell - Get Api Permissions and App Roles of Service Principals
I'm trying to retrieve the API Permissions assigned to a Service Principle using Microsoft Graph SDK for PowerShell. I tried using the below command
Get-MgServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ServicePrincipalId <Id>

However, it doesn't provide all the API Permissions. Could someone help on this?
Thanks,
Praveen

Granted API permissions to Service principal like below:

I agree with @user2250152, to get delegated permissions make use of below command:
Get-MgServicePrincipalOauth2PermissionGrant
-ServicePrincipalId <Id>


To get Application permissions, make use of below command:
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
-ServicePrincipalId <Id>


UPDATE:
To get the application permission claim, use the below script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.Read.All"

$Apps = Get-MgApplication | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "RukApp" }
$ServicePrincipals = Get-MgServicePrincipal -All
$RolesList = @()

foreach ($sp in $ServicePrincipals) {
    $RolesList += $sp.AppRoles
}

$Data = @()
foreach ($App in $Apps) {
    foreach ($Access in $App.RequiredResourceAccess) {

        foreach ($Permission in $Access.ResourceAccess) {
            $PermissionName = $null

            if ($Permission.Type -eq 'Role') {
                $PermissionName = ($RolesList | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $Permission.Id }).Value
            }

            if ($PermissionName) {
                $Data += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    'Application Display Name' = $App.DisplayName
                    'Permission Type'          = $Permission.Type
                    'Permission Value'         = $PermissionName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$Data | Format-Table -AutoSize


To check the application API permission name, refer the below
c# - Microsoft Graph API - Get users with specified app roles - Stack Overflow

Thank you We are interested in getting the Claim Value. In your example, Application.Read.All and test.read etc. Any pointers here?

It is not possible to fetch App role name via App role ID. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077564/microsoft-graph-api-get-users-with-specified-app-roles

You can try to filter via ResourceID

Sorry. I'm not looking for roles of the users/groups. I need to get the Application Permissions values

can or cannot fetch the claims??

We cannot fetch the claim value by passing ID

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Okay. Then what is the solution to get the claims in that case?

Get-MgServicePrincipalOauth2PermissionGrant should return delegated permissions, Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment returns application permissions.

Thank you We are interested in getting the Claim Value. In your example, Application.Read.All and test.read etc. Any pointers here?
