GraphAPI - request names of users that have a certain App Role
I am trying to use GraphAPI v5 in a Blazor .NET 8.0 application, to request a list of all users who have a certain AppRole assigned.
I configure the roles in Entra Admin Centre > Enterprise applications > (my app) > Users and Groups, and assign users to Roles that I defined in the application registration.
I have tried the following code in a Razor page:
@inject GraphServiceClient GSC
@inject MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler ConsentHandler

// ...

protected async Task AzTest()
{
    try
    {
        var users = await GSC.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "appRoleAssignments" };
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
}

I also found (thanks to commentor) that Directory.Read.All was a required Scope for this call to work.
My question is: how do I filter the result to find just the users with a specific Role? My organization has over 1000 users.
I have tried the following approaches:
Approach 1 - Filter
Guid roleIdGuid = new Guid("5f61fba7-ae07-4438-9f41-4c00b2540463");
// ...
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"appRoleAssignments/any(ar: ar/appRoleId eq {roleIdGuid})";

(this was suggested by Copilot). This gives a runtime error :
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Property 'appRoleId' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.

which Copilot suggests means that the API does not actually support filtering by App Role ID.
Approach 2 - Pagination
Another approach is to retrieve all users via Pagination, and then go through them in C# to check for the role ID. However, the pagination doesn't seem to work. Using the exact code from the V5 documentation:
var usersResponse = await graphServiceClient
     .Users
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration => { 
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "appRoleAssignments" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 1; 
    });

var userList = new List<User>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<User,UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient,usersResponse, (user) => { userList.Add(user); return true; });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
// (omitted the later filtering code for brevity)

This ran but I waited for over 90 seconds and it was still making API calls and responses on the await part; I'm not sure if it was stuck in an infinite loop somehow or just taking forever, but at any rate, that sort of delay isn't an acceptable solution.

Hi, I just want to double confirm whether var users = await GSC.Users.Request().GetAsync(); would throw error or not. Per my understanding, if we want to list all users in a tenant who matched some rule should at least has a permission for reading Directory such as Directory.Read.All. If you doesn't have this permission, I'm afraid it's impossible to realize your requirement.

@TinyWang ok, adding Directory.Read.All to the requested scopes makes GSC.Users.Request().GetAsync() succeed , now I guess my question moves on to what is the right Filter etc. to get the information I'm looking for

Thanks for your confirmation! And if it doesn' work, we might still need User.Read.All.

@TinyWang I have updated the question now to focus on the original question, having got past the permissions problem

Hi, based on the API document, appRoleId doesn't support filter. The properties support filter will have corresponding description. But your test result already proved this property doesn't support.

Then I had a sample before and you might use it directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78079972/14574199

Then about requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 1;  --> I test with Top1 due to I only have 2 users in my test tenant.... You might use Top 999... similar to this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/78720008/14574199

appRoleId doesn't support filter from the API document. As you can see that principalDisplayName supports filter. So that I agree with you that we need to get all the users and then get the users assigned specific roles by ourselves.

About the Graph API Pagination, we could set page size to 999 to minimize the number of requests and I'm afraid top 1 is the reason why you waited for so long.
Then our codes shall be similar to
var usersResponse = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration => { 
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "appRoleAssignments" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 999; 
    });

var userList = new List<User>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<User,UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(graphServiceClient,usersResponse, (user) => { userList.Add(user); return true; });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

List<User> result = new List<User>();
foreach (var tempUser in userList) {
    var roles = tempUser.AppRoleAssignments;
    foreach(var role in roles) {
        if (role.AppRoleId.ToString() == "role_id_here")
        {
            result.Add(tempUser);
            break;
        }
    }
}


I've observed that when requesting "top 999" it only seems to return top 100 ?

thank you for your reply, different API might have different behavior for the Maximin top count. Based on your description, I searched for the API and I found In server-side paging, the Microsoft Graph service returns a default number of results in a single page without the client specifying the number of results to return using $top. For example, the GET /users endpoint returns a default of 100 results in a single page. from this link. I'm afraid the list user API changed the max top value.. I remembered that it

was 999 before. And maybe I just made a mistake in my memory. Any way, could you please let me know whether it worked for your or not? Did you face the waiting-for-so-long issue?

There are actually more users in the tenant than I thought (over 20,000), so even pages of 999 is too slow ; can you think of any possible filter I could use to narrow down the list a bit?  The endsWith(mail, 'mydomain.com') filter works by itself, but the API doesn't appear to support using that at the same time as the Expand parameter .

I'm afraid you have to try other filters, I test in my side with request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments&$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'tiny2@xx.onmicrosoft.com' which worked well but if I used $expand=appRoleAssignments&$filter=endswith(userPrincipalName,'tiny2@xx.onmicrosoft.com'), it gave me unsupported query error even if this property support to filter with endswith. It's weird.

I'm afraid that we could have a workaround to create a group which adding all users having specific app role into it. I found this case which used powershell script. We could also create a powershell script to find out all the users and add users into that group.

if I understand correctly, the powershell script is applying the filter and then making further calls one by one to check the appRoleAssignment for each user. Not ideal

Hi, I'm sorry that I didn't express my idea clearly. What I mean is that we can try powershell to do a task like a background service to help us find all the users and then add them into a group so that we don't care about the performance. The link I shared, hmm I just want you see a powershell sample for calling MS graph API, some of the script might be similar but are not the same.

OK. to clarify, you're saying that instead of using Roles for this task, in the application registration, I would be better to use Groups instead?

yes, since we are not able to have a good api to do this task and get all the users who have a specific role, for maintance in future, maybe create a group for these users might be another option. By the way, we might even give role to the group. API for list group members and list memberOf group are available.

This answer summarises discussion from comments
There is currently (July 2024) no way to efficiently list all users with a particular App Role; the only way is to enumerate all users and check their role at application level, which is unacceptably slow if the tenant contains 20,000+ users for example.
Instead, the system could be designed to use Groups instead of App Roles . The API does support listing members of a Group.
